# Reliable way to pass Object variable to method that expects Object parameter

Tags: vb.net, object, struct, boxing

The normal expected semantics of a reference type is that it should behave as an object identifier.  If some variable holds a reference to the 5483rd object a program created, passing that variable to a method should give it a reference to the 5483rd object.  VB.NET mostly works like this, but with a rather curious exception: even in the `Option Strict On` dialect, attempting pass such a variable of type `Object` to a method which takes a parameter of that type, copy one `Object` variable to another, or otherwise cause an "rvalue" of type `Object` [to borrow C terminology] to be stored to an "lvalue" of that type, will sometimes result in the compiler storing a reference to a different object.

Is there any nice way to avoid this in cases where code does not know, and shouldn't have to care, about the types of objects it's dealing with?

If one can have either of the involved operands be of a type other than `Object`, there is no problem.  *Within* a generic method, variables of its generic type will also work correctly even when that type happens to be `Object`.  Parameters which are of the generic type, however, will be treated as `Object` when the type is invoked using that type.

Consider the methods:

```
Function MakeNewWeakReference(Obj As Object) As WeakReference
   Return New WeakReference(Obj)
End Function 

Function GetWeakReferenceTargetOrDefault(WR as WeakReference, DefaultValue as Object) _
     As Object
   Dim WasTarget as Object = WR.Target
   If WasTarget IsNot Nothing Then Return WasTarget
   Return DefaultValue
End Function
```

One would expect that the first function would return a WeakReference that will remain alive as long as the passed-in object is.  One would further expect that if the second function is given a WeakReference that is still alive, the method would return a reference that would keep it alive.  Unfortunately, that assumption will fail if the reference refers to a boxed non-primitive value type.  In that case, the first method will return a weak reference to a new copy of the boxed value that won't be kept alive by the original reference, and the second will return a new copy of the boxed value that won't keep the one in the weak reference alive.

If one changed the methods to be generic:

```
Function MakeNewWeakReference(Of T As Class)(Obj As T) As WeakReference
   Return New WeakReference(Obj)
End Function 

Function GetWeakReferenceTargetOrDefault(Of T As Class)(WR as WeakReference, _
             DefaultValue as T) As T
   Dim WasTarget as T = TryCast(WR.Target, T)
   If WasTarget IsNot Nothing Then Return WasTarget
   Return DefaultValue
End Function
```

that would avoid the problem *within the methods*, even if one were to invoke `MakeNewWeakReference(Of Object)` or `GetWeakReferenceTargetOrDefault(Of Object)`.  Unfortunately, if one were to try to use either method with a parameter of type `Object`, and either the thing being stored (in the first case) or the variable it was being stored to (in the second) was also type `Object`, the problem would still occur at the method's invocation or when storing its return value.  If one put all of one's code into a generic class and only ever used it with a type parameter of Object, but made sure to always `TryCast` things of type `Object` to the generic type (such operation should never actually fail if the generic type happens to be `Object`) that would work to solve the problem, but would be rather ugly.  Is there a clean way to specify that a variable should be allowed to hold a reference to any type of heap object the way `Object` can, but should always behave with reference semantics the way all other reference types do?

BTW, some directly-runnable test code:

```
Sub ObjTest(O1 As Object)
    Debug.Print("Testing type {0} (value is {1})", O1.GetType, O1)
    Dim O2 As Object
    Dim wr As New WeakReference(O1)

    O2 = O1 ' source and destination are type Object--not identity preserving

    Debug.Print("Ref-equality after assignment: {0}", O2 Is O1)
    Debug.Print("Ref-equality with itself: {0}", Object.ReferenceEquals(O1, O1))
    GC.Collect()
    Debug.Print("Weak reference still alive? {0}", wr.IsAlive)
    Debug.Print("Value was {0}", O1) ' Ensure O1 is still alive
End Sub

Sub ObjTest()
    ObjTest("Hey")
    ObjTest(1)
    ObjTest(1D)
End Sub
```

There's no real reason why the type of object given to the `ObjTest(Object)` method should have to care what kind of object it's given, but all three tests that print `true` with a class object like `String` or a primitive value type like `Int32` fail with a non-primitive value type like `Decimal`.  Is there any nice way to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I removed all this part because it is not applicable anymore to the new text of the question)

--- SAMPLE CODE (original question)

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim Obj As Object

        'Argument as Object treated as String
        Obj = "converting into string although still is an object"
        Dim outString As String = ObjToString(Obj)

        'Is, complex behaviour; equals (=), always the same
        Obj = "This one is 1"
        Dim is1 As Integer = IsVsEqual(Obj, False)  '1
        Dim equal1 As Integer = IsVsEqual(Obj, True) '1
        Obj = 1.0d 'This one 2
        Dim outIndex2 As Integer = IsVsEqual(Obj, False) '2
        Dim equal2 As Integer = IsVsEqual(Obj, True)  '1

    End Sub

    Private Function ObjToString(obj As Object) As String

        Dim nowIWantString As String = obj.ToString()
        nowIWantString = nowIWantString & " -- now string 100%"

        Return nowIWantString
    End Function

    Private Function IsVsEqual(obj As Object, tryEqual As Boolean) As Integer

        Dim obj2 As Object = obj
        Dim outIndex As Integer = 0
        If (tryEqual) Then
            If (obj2 = obj) Then
                outIndex = 1
            Else
                outIndex = 2
            End If
        Else
            If (obj2 Is obj) Then
                outIndex = 1
            Else
                outIndex = 2
            End If
        End If

    Return outIndex
End Function

End Class
```

--- ANSWER TO THE UPDATED QUESTION

I have to recognise that I am somehow impressed with the results you are showing. I haven't ever looked at all this in detail but the fact of having two different treatments for two different groups of types; and getting to the point of provoking `ReferenceEquals(sameObject, sameObject) = False` is certainly curious. Just a quick summary of your example:

```
Dim O1 As Object = new Object
If Not Object.ReferenceEquals(O1, O1) Then 
    'This object will show the "quirky behaviour"
End If
```

Making an `Object Type` variable going through this condition is as easy as doing `O1 = 2D`. You have also observed that, in these cases, the `WeakReference` has to be defined slightly different: `wr = New WeakReference(CType(quirkyObj, ValueType))`.

All this is certainly interesting (more than what I thought before reading this last question :)), although can be avoided by relying on codes like this one (or the one above):

```
Public Function dealWithNumObjects(a As Object) As Object

    Dim outObject As Object = a

    If (TypeOf a Is Double) Then
        'Do operations as double
    ElseIf (TypeOf a Is Decimal) Then
        'Do operations as decimal
    ElseIf (TypeOf a Is Integer) Then
        'Do operations as integer
    End If

    Return outObject
End Function
```

Which can be used like this:

```
Dim input As Object
input = 5D 'Decimal
Dim outputDecimal As Decimal = DirectCast(dealWithNumObjects(input), Decimal)
input = 5.0 'Double
Dim outputDouble As Double = DirectCast(dealWithNumObjects(input), Double)
input = 5 'Integer
Dim outputInteger As Integer = DirectCast(dealWithNumObjects(input), Integer)
```

This approach looks just at values and thus being quirky or not does not really matter (`Decimal` is quirky but neither `Double` nor `Integer` and this method works fine with all of them).

In summary: before reading your example, I would have said: avoid problems and just use objects as "temporary holders of values", convert them into the target type ASAP and deal with the target type. After reading your answer, I do recognise that your methodology seems quite solid ("pretty ugly"? Why? I like the `ReferenceEquals` approach but if you don't like it and just want to determine if the type is primitive you can rely on `O1.GetType().IsPrimitive`) and might have some applicability. I cannot come up with a better way to do things than in your example: you are able to locate the "quirky" types and to keep a WeakReference. I guess that this is the maximum you can get under these conditions.

Comment: The `O1 = 1.0d;` should create a new heap object holding a boxed `Decimal`, and store a reference to that heap object into `O1`.  It does so.  The statement `V1 = CType(O1, ValueType);` makes `V1 refer to that same object, and `O5 = V1;` makes `O5` also refer to that same object.  The statement which has the least excuse for creating a new object, `O2 = O1;` is the one which does so.  Using the `Is` operator on reference types always tests reference equality; it cannot be overloaded to do anything else.  The `ReferenceEquals` method will fail to test reference equality...

Comment: ...if one or both of its operands are values of type `Object`, and the two operands both refer to the same instance of a non-primitive value type.  In that scenario, VB6 doesn't pass references to that instance, but creates for each value of type `Object` a new heap object and passes a reference to that.

Comment: @supercat So you are saying that, in VB6, O2 Is O1 (true) and that you are looking for a way to emulate this behaviour in VB.NET?

Comment: If you want to create examples that show the problem, it's simple: store into a variable of type `Object` a reference to any boxed non-primitive data type (I used a `Decimal`, but any will work) and either copy that variable to another of type `Object`, or pass it to a method which takes an `Object` parameter.  The assignment or parameter-passing operation will copy or pass a reference to a new object instance containing the same data.  Other reference types do not exhibit such behavior.

Comment: @supercat I keep having the same ideas: if in VB6 it was possible (via Variant) and now is not (because of the Covariance (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx), isn't?) or not as evident. Why intending to go back to this behaviour rather than intending to maximise it or understand its advantanges? If you use Object bear in mind the performance of Is when boxing/unboxing it. I mean... if this is theoretical curiosity my approach would be "this is how things are now"; if this is for practical reasons, "adapt yourself to what you have".

Comment: @supercat the whole point of my answer was highlighting that the behaviour is logical (from a theoretical point of view) and that everything is as expected (and there is no difference VB.NET/C#; at least, none I know); that it is possible to rely on other means (you can write virtually any piece of code by using "Is"/"ReferenceEquals" only when compelled to do so). I cannot add more to this, mainly because I wouldn't ever recommend to look for a way to circumvent the normal behaviour of a language (other than avoiding using this part). Hopefully you have found useful something of this.

Comment: I don't like the way the VB6 `Variant` type works; I mention it because VB6 to VB.NET tools use `Object` as a replacement for `Variant` and I'm guessing VB.NET may be trying to make it act the way a VB6 `Variant` might act if one could assign a structure type to it (which one can't do in VB6).

Comment: @supercat perhaps you should accept what you have rather than liking/disliking it :) If you deal with Object you have to accept the implications of boxing/unboxing/covariance/contravariance. If you don't like all this, just don't use Objects or don't put yourself in this kind of situations (for example, never using "Is" for the variables you create/affect, what is quite doable); but avoiding this behaviour is either impossible or complicating things too much (and for what? when you have tons of alternatives). Anyway... I guess that my position is clear. Sorry but I cannot be of further help.

Comment: Let me ask this question, then: Suppose I have receive a parameter `Obj` of type `Object`, I want to call a method which takes a parameter of type `Object`, and I want that method to receive a reference to the actual object pointed to by `Obj`.  Is there any way I can do so without having to use different code for the where `Obj` refers to a non-primitive value-type object than for the case where `Obj` refers to a class object?

Comment: @supercat I will answer this question with a small example I will include in brief (give me some minutes, I am doing something else)

Comment: @supercat take a look at the code in my last update; I hope that these functions will answer all your doubts.

Comment: The "complex behavior" stems not from the behavior of `Is`, but rather from the behavior of the first assignment statement. The `Is` operator works 100% correctly to report whether `obj` and `obj2` refer to the same object. The problem is that it's hard for a routine that can accept any `Object` to store or pass around the received object in a manner that preserves its identity.

Comment: @supercat I am intending to simplify ideas. You want something simple, always working and easily definable? Rely on "=" (or Equals) it takes into account just values and you can build anything by relying only on it. I am not saying that Is does not work; since the start I have let very clear that EVERYTHING WORKS AS EXPECTED and the base for my reply has been proving that this behaviour is actually perfectly logical (on account of each function does). There is no problem, just a complex reality; you have 2 options: either understanding this reality or avoiding it (out of space)

Comment: @supercat you were asking whether there is any way to avoid this behaviour (why this behaviour happens and why VB.NET does that). My answer has consisted firstly in proving that this behaviour is logical (and addressing you to understand it better) and secondly in proposing you a practical alternative: you can avoid all that easily by not using operators like "Is" under certain conditions. I think that I have spent a pretty long time on this answer and my point is more than clear (my point and the reality: don't think that you have any other option on top of the two proposed ones).

Comment: The `=` operator is not available on `Object` in the `Option Strict On` dialect of vb.net (the `Option Strict Off` dialect has enough quirks that it should never be used for any purpose but porting VB6 code).  If `O1` is an `Object` which holds a boxed `Decimal`, `Object.Equals(O1,O1)` is about 50 times as slow as it would be if `O1` were any other reference type. `Object.Equals(TryCast(O1,ValueType),TryCast(O1,ValueType))` is only about twice as slow as it should be, but it's ugly and will fail if `O1` isn't a boxed value type.

Comment: @supercat I do understand your point and you should also understand mine. I usually don't have the kind of problems you refer because of having a "practical way of coding". The only help I can provide you is proposing the best proceeding on these lines. What I do with "Object" type variables? I Use them as less as possible; when using them, I perform a conversion to the target type ASAP (Object as argument to a function and DirectCast inside it to convert to decimal, for example). This is all the help I can provide, if you don't like it, you should wait for a different answer.

Comment: Sometimes `Object` is unavoidable, alas, since one may need to allow arbitrary kinds of information to be passed through methods.  For example, a database wrapper method may have to take a field-name string and return an `Object` representing the content of that field.  That `Object` may hold a numeric primitive, a struct like `DateTime`, a `String`, a `Byte[]`, or who knows what else.  The wrapper could document that if the database returns a value-type instance, it will return a reference to a different instance holding the same data; most client code wouldn't care about such things...

Comment: ...but because there are some cases where it could, the behavior should be documented if it occurs; being able to avoid the behavior would avoid the need to document it.  To put it another way, defensive coding requires that one examine everything that "might" cause a problem, to ensure that it won't.  The fact that some behavioral quirk is "unlikely" to cause a problem doesn't mean one should simply ignore it.  One must either document the quirk and ensure it won't cause trouble, or else change code to eliminate it; the latter approach would seem preferable any time it's practical.

Comment: @supercat I am not sure about the point of continuing this. I have shown you how I use objects (and haven't ever had a problem): I don't check for the Type integrity (via Is) and thus I don't have any problem. I have also explained you that the "weird behaviour" is perfectly understood and known (is not a bug or anything like this), but is complex and can easily be avoided.

Comment: @supercat you aren't new here and know the rules: you have to post clear and helpful-to-others questions; what I am not sure that is the case (as far as it took me a pretty long time to understand what you want exactly what, honestly, is still not 100% clear). You have to make your level best to help others with the question/answer and you seem to be doing the contrary. You want to see an intrinsic complexity in something so simple like: Dim inputObj as Object function(inputArg as Object) dim internalDecimal as Decimal = DirectCast(inputArc, Decimal) -> this is what everyone does and...

Comment: @supercat ... is not a problem at all. Logically is not the ideal scenario (when relying on a replacement for anything has been the ideal scenario?) but is perfectly fine option which can be used as many times as required (I use it on a regular basis). If you don't like that, change the language (although would find the same everywhere), but I am not sure about the point of continue and continue saying the same; if you have a doubt, I have given a different view, if you don't like it, look for a different one (or look for the next answerer... not too likely to happen)...

Comment: @supercat put yourself in my position: what would you do with someone who keep asking and asking questions which you consider already answered? Without showing any kind of appreciation and thinking that you are here to answer him (because I seriously doubt that you are doing this for anyone else other than yourself; also you are not paying me now, isn't it?). You are mixing up kindness with obligation and this is a really sad confusion. If you consider that my answer is fine do what you are supposed to do, otherwise wait for the next answerer. Thanks.

Comment: It is clear that we are talking past each other.  I am obviously not conveying why I find the vb.net behavior troublesome.  I appreciate your efforts, and apologize for having not been clear enough in what I'm after.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: @supercat you are welcome. But I think that you should just make your ideas clearer via simple examples (as the ones I proposed). Put yourself in a real scenario and intend to do the simplistic treatment I talked about: Object just when required (argument for the function, for example), DirectCast and then use the given variable with the target type. Ideally, coming up with structures avoiding the utilisation of Objects at all (pretty doable most of the times). If this is not enough, review the MSDN information on the matter (mainly covariance/contravariance) -> this is all what I can say.

Comment: I rewrote the question to show a somewhat more realistic problem: a method gets a parameter of type `Object` and expects to use it with Framework methods that also use type `Object`.  Such methods shouldn't have to know nor care about the types of instances targeted by the passed in `Object` references, but I haven't found any nice type-independent way to do something like construct a weak reference to the actual object instance that was passed in.

Comment: @supercat if I update my answer to account your new example (hint: basically the same than before; complex reality which can/should be avoided) would you award me the question and consider this issue closed? As you can see, there is not too much people interested in all this (note that, I wasn't the one downvoting the question). I am not interested in continuing either and thus the only interested person seems to be you: not too fair, don't you think?

Comment: No problem.  It's a corner case that bit me when I was trying to design a weak interning dictionary, a concept that also seems to have not generated a whole lot of interest even though it can greatly improve the performance of hierarchical data structures.

Comment: @supercat OK. I was expecting a "NO! How you dare!!" but well... thanks (although it has surely being deserved :)). Let me update my answer to your new question.

Comment: @supercat I have updated my answer. As you can read there, I am a bit impressed with your new example; haven't read it before asking you for awarding me this question. Now I see much more point on what you ask (although still prefer my option) and cannot find any way to answer it "properly", that is, as you want (is there FOR SURE a better way?). If you want to unaward me this question, I would find it perfectly normal: I have spent a pretty long time here but questions are not awarded on account of the spent time. In any case, I hope that now both our positions are completely clear :)

Comment: Thanks for your new answer.  There is another approach which works but has its own odd quirkiness: define a method with a class-constrained generic type parameter, and invoke it using `Object` as the type.  That works, sorta, but one has to use `CType` or `TryCast` all the time when trying to store an `Object` into a variable of that type.  Further, if a method takes a parameter of that generic type, invoking the method with `Object` as the generic type means its parameters are seen as type `Object`, subject to the weird behavior.  I wonder if *any* production code relies upon this behavior?

Comment: @supercat " I wonder if any production code relies upon this behavior?" I don't think so; weird/complex things are not too popular in the commercial world; much less when there are ways to avoid the weirdness (, as shown in the codes above).

Comment: If the only `Option Strict On` code anywhere in the world that relies upon the weirdness is things whose sole purpose is to demonstrate and gripe about it, I wonder if there would be any reason for MS not to eliminate it in future versions of VS (or at minimum have a configurable option to do so).  I'm pretty certain that having the weirdness makes `o2 = o1` slower than it otherwise would be even when it causes no other problem, so if nothing needs the weird behavior eliminating it would be a pure "win".

Comment: @supercat You can contact Microsoft or post a new more-descriptive (, much briefer) question with a more descriptive title which can attract more people to answer it. I don't think that this is an intended behaviour, but a bad consequence (out of many other ones) of the complex boxing/unboxing reality + covariance/contravariance. Most likely, nobody at Microsoft thinks that the right output from comparing the same object with itself should be "false" (no matter how intrincate the specific situation is). As said: work on making your speech more to-the-point and you can try it again :)

Comment: How would you suggest I word the question?  The biggest problem is that passing a received parameter of type `Object` to a method which takes an `Object` doesn't always pass the reference, but I've characterized the exact behavior more precisely than that and I would think such characterization would be useful information.

Comment: @supercat I am the one who has replied you but nobody else did it: you didn't attract enough attention; and my impression is that it was because of having a "too dense" question. I don't like too much getting involved in this kind of discussions (am a practical programmer) but I understand that there are quite a few people who do enjoy it. Simple title + simple example showing the problem and a couple of paragraphs of light explanations are much more attractive and prone to trigger a discussion than what you did. But this is just my impression.

Answer (score 1):

Note that VB injects calls to `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue` which is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.getobjectvalue.aspx) to exactly do what you're noticing: Return a "boxed *copy* of `obj` if it is a value class; otherwise `obj` itself is returned."

In fact the documentation goes on to say, if the value type is immutable it returns the same object passed in. (It does not explain how immutability is determined, and it's an `InternalCall` :-( )

It seems `Decimal`, `Date`, and, of course, a user-defined `Structure` are seen as mutable by the CLR.

To actually attempt to answer your question: VB.NET does not call `GetObjectValue`, but rather directly uses the MSIL `box` command when using a generic type:

```
Sub Assign(Of T)(ByRef lvalue As T, ByRef rvalue As T)
  lvalue = rvalue
  If Not Object.ReferenceEquals(lvalue, rvalue) Then _
    Console.WriteLine("Ref-equality lost even generically!")
End Sub
```

This does NOT write anything for the types I've tried, but `GetObjectValue` is called at the callsite :-(

(BTW This is one case where `ReferenceEquals` is available when `Is` is not.)

The comments from the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/runtimehelpers.cs#8b0963ea6ed7d6fc):

```cs
  // GetObjectValue is intended to allow value classes to be manipulated as 'Object'
  // but have aliasing behavior of a value class.  The intent is that you would use
  // this function just before an assignment to a variable of type 'Object'.  If the
  // value being assigned is a mutable value class, then a shallow copy is returned
  // (because value classes have copy semantics), but otherwise the object itself
  // is returned.
  //
  // Note: VB calls this method when they're about to assign to an Object
  // or pass it as a parameter.  The goal is to make sure that boxed
  // value types work identical to unboxed value types - ie, they get
  // cloned when you pass them around, and are always passed by value.
  // Of course, reference types are not cloned.
```

I don't have further comments to make at this stage -- just consolidating into one place.

I had this link stored in my Chrome bookmarks: [RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue why needed](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.vb/2006-10/msg00033.html). I don't recall how long ago I stored it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm curious at the history of that method and its incorporation into VB.  It could have represented sensible and useful behavior if there were distinct variable types for "value of any type" and "reference to any heap object", and the behavior only applied to the former type [btw, it would also have been helpful to have a "reference to any heap object" type which would disallow autoboxing, so constructs like `Object.ReferenceEquals(someObject, someValueType)` which can never have any useful meaning would refuse to compile].

Comment: I'm also curious as to the cases where the behavior could be usefully applied to `Object` in code compiled with `Option Strict On`.  If there were a type which represented "value of any type", the compiler allowed late binding with that type even in `Option Strict On` mode, and one could avoid unwanted copying by a cast or coercion to `System.Object`, then the implicit copying could be helpful.  Since `Option Strict On` doesn't allow any late binding, however, it's unclear what kind of mutation VB.NET could be trying to protect against.

Comment: In reply to your first comment, note that, as I imply at the bottom of my answer, VB.NET refuses to allow `Is` to be applied to two general `Ts`. (It does allow `Is Nothing`.)

Comment: The `Is` operator demands a reference type, and is unwilling to box a value type to get it; it's too bad there's no way to make any other method's parameter behave like that.  BTW, `Is` will accept class-constrained generics.

Comment: The more I think about this, the more curious I am about the history and intention of that method.  The ability to declare storage locations as having value semantics even when they hold a class reference could be helpful, but boxed value types are among the least useful places to apply such behavior.  I appreciate the advantages of having Framework-defined assignment operators versus the overloadable-assignment free-for-all of C++, but I think a .NET-style framework with a richer type system could have offered the best of both worlds.

Comment: Fundamentally, an object of a mutable class like an `int[]` can encapsulate a value in two ways: it can hold the only reference, anywhere in the universe, to an array, or it can hold a sharable reference to an array that's never going to change (provided everyone with a reference agrees not to share it with any code that might modify it).  In most cases, either the holder of a reference will either know whether it encapsulates an unshared mutable value, a shared immutable value, or an entity's identity, or the holder will be a collection whose creator knew that.

Comment: As implied by the accepted answer, one workaround, when applicable, is to cast to `ValueType`, then `GetObjectValue` is not called, as mentioned [here](http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/543783-runtimehelpers-getobjectvalue-discussion#post2122396).

Comment: If something is *known* to be a value type, then casting it to `ValueType` before passing to something that expects `Object` will avoid the time-wasting and semantically-incorrect copy operation, but what of a method that accepts an `Object`?  For example, if what I want is `Sub DoTwice(Object O) : DoIt(O) : DoIt(O) : End Sub` should I really have to write it as...

Comment: ...something like `Sub DoTwice(Object O) : Dim V = TryCast(O, ValueType) : If V IsNot Nothing Then DoIt(V) : DoIt(V): Else DoIt(O) : DoIt(O) : End If : End Sub`?  Having to do an extra type-check at run-time for the sole purpose of preventing a special-case behavior by the compiler which is, so far as I can tell, *always* harmful in `Strict On` mode [can anyone identify a single case where the behavior is actually helpful in `Strict On` code]?